# "while: Expression Syntax" in FreeBSD

Tags: ssh, cmd, freebsd

I hav problem with my Script.
I use FreeBSD and SSH to start this script:

grep -rl '=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(""),' . | while read FILENAME; do sed -i -e '$d' $FILENAME; echo "$FILENAME"; done

When i start, the SSH get error:

**while: Expression Syntax.**

Please help me!!
PS: Sorry for my English i from Ukraine.

Comment: You're probably using the wrong shell - it looks like it needs to be bash or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `csh`, right? Try it in `bash`, the syntax you posted works for me on FreeBSD in `bash` and `sh`. `sh` is part of the base system, but you can install `bash` e.g. with `pkg_add -r bash`.

Comment: I tried to run the command you said this is the result. 
%pkg_add -r bash
Fetching ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/ports/amd64/packages-8-stable/Latest/bash.tbz... Done.
pkg_add: package 'bash-4.2.20' or its older version already installed

Comment: So you already have it; how about running it? Type `exec /usr/local/bin/bash` to switch to `bash` just for one session, or change your shell to `bash` permanently using `chsh` and then login again.

Comment: i create the file 1.sh and uplouded it to server, then start him with command sh 1.sh and hi starting normall, but then it rename all js file to .js-e